# php / styling / of date issue

Tags: php

We are just converting our blog to match our site style.

The date of the POST ( for a blog post is )

```
<?php echo date($OptionsVis["date_format"],strtotime($Post["publish_date"])); ?>
```

Which gives : 08 JAN

But I want to represent the date like this:

```
       <div class="post-list-date">
            <h1>08</h1>
            <h2>JAN</h2>
        </div>
```

Can you think of a way I can split my php to get what I am after. Without buggering around with my entire blog system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest two `$OptionsVis` values (`date_format_main`, `date_format_sub`). Then, do two separate `date()` calls, one for in `<h1>` and another for in `<h2>` like so:

```
$date_h1 = date($OptionsVis["date_format_main"], strtotime($Post["publish_date"]));
$date_h2 = date($OptionsVis["date_format_sub"], strtotime($Post["publish_date"]));
```

If this is not possible, and you know the date format will always be the same, you could do:

```
$date = date($OptionsVis["date_format"], strtotime($Post["publish_date"]));
list($date_h1, $date_h2) = explode(" ", $date, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just post-process the output:

```
<?php
    $date = date(... existing code...);
    list($d, $m) = explode(' ', $date);
?>
<div class="post-list-date">
    <h1><?php echo $d; ?></h1>
    <h2><?php echo $m; ?></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was typing, but I included `2` as the third parameter of explode, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Although the semantics of your HTML is somewhat unusual (h tags are usually reserved for text headers that relate to the content), I would try something like the following:

```
$date_array = explode(" ", date($OptionsVis["date_format"],strtotime($Post["publish_date"])));

$date_html = "<div class=\"post-list-date\"><h1>".$date_array[0]."</h1><h2>".$date_array[1]."</h2></div>";

echo $date_html;
```

Hope this helps, happy coding.